How to get autofill for Safari family-name and other fields?
For example I have following HTML code:
<input type="text" id="ec-4637-c0d43944ac79" name="ec-4637-c0d43944ac79" class="input" data-validatable="true" placeholder="" value="" autocomplete="given-name">
<input type="text" id="2b-4505-27b2476c8b29" name="2b-4505-27b2476c8b29" class="input" data-validatable="true" placeholder="" value="" autocomplete="family-name">
<input type="tel" id="90-a8e71fbdaeab" name="90-a8e71fbdaeab" class="input" data-validatable="true" placeholder="" value="" autocomplete="tel">
<textarea id="f6-a6946" class="input" type="email" rows="1" name="f6-a6946" style="resize: none;" placeholder="" value="" autocomplete="email"></textarea>

in Chrome and other Browser, autofill works, also works in Android phone but in Safari, only first-name and telephone is autofilled, not the other Fields, why?
But if i click the family-name field and go to Edit -> 'Autofill Form' in Safari, it will fill the family name as well. Same thing for other Fields like email, address.
Can anyone help me fixing the problem ?
